# How to calculate image histogram without normalizing data in Matlab

Tags: matlab, image-processing, histogram, normalization

I have an image `I` which pixel intensities fall within the range of 0-1. I can calculate the image histogram by normalizing it but I found the curves is not exactly the same as the histogram of raw data. This will cause some issue for the later peaks finding process(See attached two images). 
[image: Histogram of Raw data, only 1 peak has been found on the histogram][image: Histogram of Normalized data,2 peaks has been found on the histogram]

My question is in Matlab, is there any way I can plot the image histogram without normalization the data so that I can keep the curve shape unchanged? This will benefit for those raw images when their pixel intensities are not within 0-1 ranges. Currently, I cannot calculate their histogram if I don't normalize the data.

The Matlab code for normalization and histogram calculation is attached. Any suggestion will be appreciated!

```
h = imhist(mat2gray(I));
```

Comment: Have you tried [histogram](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/histogram.html)?

Comment: I'm confused. I see 2 histograms here. one has values between about 160 to 240 and one that looks like the histogram after normalization. How did you get the first histogram if you cannot calculate it?

Comment: @Piglet The data I listed here is the one which raw data falls into 0-1 ranges. I have other data which the raw data cannot fall into 0-1 ranges. This is just an example to say the curves before and after is different.

Comment: of course the curve is different befor and after normalization. that's the whole idea behind this. you stretch it across the entire value range. please clarify your question. It's not clear what you want. why do you normalize in the first place? you don't get  any new information by that. you just risk like that new peak. what do you mean with "I cannot calculate their histogram". do you get an error message or what?

Comment: @Piglet sorry for the confusion. What I mean I cannot calculate their histogram is because imhist function cannot take any image which intensity doesn't fall into 0-1 ranges. I just try to use histogram instead of using imhist and it works. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

[Documentation of `imhist`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/imhist.html) tells us that the function checks the data type of the input and scale the values accordingly. Therefore, without testing with your attached data, this may work:

```
h = imhist(uint8(I));
```

An alternatively you may scale the integer-representation to floating-representation, by either using argument of [`mat2gray`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/mat2gray.html)

```
h = imhist(mat2gray(I, [0,255]));
```

or just divide it.

```
h = imhist(I/255);
```

Answer (score 0):

The imhist answer in this thread describing normalizing or casting is completely correctly. Alternatively, you could use the histogram function in MATLAB which will work with unnormalized floating point data:

```
A = 255*rand(500,500);
histogram(A);
```